# How is data written to HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to understand how is data writing managed in HDFS by reading [hadoop-2.4.1 documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html).

According to the following schema :

[image: HDFS architecture]

whenever a client writes something to HDFS, he has no contact with the namenode and is in charge of chunking and replication. I assume that in this case, the client is a machine running an HDFS shell (or equivalent).

However, I don't understand how this is managed.
Indeed, according to the same documentation :

> The DataNodes also perform block creation, deletion, and replication upon instruction from the NameNode.

Is the schema presented above correct ? If so,

- is the namenode only informed of new files when it receives a Blockreport (which can take time, I suppose) ?
- why does the client write to multiple nodes ?

  If this schema is not correct, how is file creation working with HDFs ?

Answer (score 2):

As you said DataNodes are responsible for serving read/write requests and block creation/deletion/replication.

Then they send on a regular basis **“HeartBeats”** ( state of health report)  and **“BlockReport”**( list of blocks on the DataNode) to the NameNode.

According to [this article](http://bradhedlund.com/2011/09/10/understanding-hadoop-clusters-and-the-network/):

> Data Nodes send heartbeats to the Name Node every **3 seconds** via a TCP
>   handshake, ...  **Every tenth heartbeat is a Block Report**,
>   where the Data Node tells the Name Node about all the blocks it has.

So block reports are done every 30 seconds, I don't think that this may affect Hadoop jobs because in general they are independent jobs.

For your question:

> why does the client write to multiple nodes ?

I'll say that actually, **the client writes to just one datanode and tell him to send data to other datanodes**(*see this [link](http://bigdatahandler.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/HDFS.pdf) picture: CLIENT START WRITING DATA* ), but this is transparent. That's why your schema considers that the client is the one who is writing to multiple nodes

Comment: According to the article you linked, the client asks where to write the blocks to the namenode before (http://bradhedlund.s3.amazonaws.com/2011/hadoop-network-intro/Writing-Files-to-HDFS-s.png). That would make the above schema wrong, which is the core of my question :) Could you confirm it ?

Comment: Yes I think , see this awsome [link](http://bigdatahandler.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/HDFS.pdf) too.